# Get/set window line, column without navigating to window

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, functions

I'm looking for three functions (line, col, cursor) in nvim that takes an extra parameter window number so that I don't need to first navigate to the window and then navigate away.

The reason is if I navigate the window, I will see a quick flash on the screen.